# How does GetFiles() actually search the files - issue with Wildcard filter

Tags: vb.net

Our web aspx has a list built by GetFiles() that was searching for `04834*.pdf`

*the files are stored in the format of `5 char Login Code` and a `date mm/dd/yy` format*

For an unknown reason we had this file show up for user 03471: (no spaces)

- `03471`013115.pdf
- `03471`022815.pdf
- **`03268`033115.pdf**
- `03471`033115.pdf

The code has been gone over multiple times and is considered sound, I have no clue why this 1 other file `02384030415.pdf` would show up in this list.

**Why is GetFiles() comparing something other than the actual file name?**

*Just incase it matters win 7 gave me the list I expected ( locally ) - the server running 2k8 standard we received the bad file in the list.*

EDIT: 
Code used to get files

```
Dim loginNumber as String 
loginNumber = "04834"
Dim dir As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(folderVariable).ToString())
Dim files As FileInfo() = dir.GetFiles(loginNumber & "*.pdf")
```

*PS: It does currently have a lambda expression filtering a second time to ensure correct results but my question is why I'm getting incorrect results initially?*

EDIT VIA CHRIS:

*Please note that the dates on the live server will match the filenames*

[image]

Comment: Was this just a one-off or does it happen every time you use that specific search?

Comment: I would question whether loginNumber has the leading zero or not...

Comment: @TheBlueDog , Everytime on the live server - never locally

Comment: @jmoreno - Yes tested on live server - the loginNumber does include the 0

Comment: I'm not sure where I'm going with this yet, but does `02384030415.pdf` actually exist? Not something related to a corrupt filename or similar?

Comment: Your code does not compile. You cannot declare `dir` as `DirectoryInfo` then try to assign it a String.

Comment: @OneFineDay: I'd say it's a typo, he probably means `DirectoryInfo(folderVariable.ToString())`. Uneven number of parentheses and all that ...

Comment: I try not to assume things, but your probably right.

Comment: How does your unexpected file look in long file name format?  According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63(v=vs.110).aspx, the search pattern checks again 8.3 file name format and long file name format.

Comment: @OneFineDay: I hear ya!

Comment: @Shar1er80 TBH - I am not certain how to view the Long file name of the file.

Comment: If you go to that folder in the command prompt and issue this command:  `dir /X`, what are the short names for those files?  Do they match your search criteria?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - Updated above

Comment: @DonThomasBoyle I hope you find your answer soon, sorry I couldn't help you. I thought about the short and long format as well, but that isn't the issue and hence why I didn't mention it.